# ¿Cómo seleccionar los checkbox seleccionados y que tienen cierto atributo específico?

Tags: javascript

Quiero obtener el listado de inputs de tipo checkbox que estén seleccionados y que tengan el atributo data-checkboxinsumo. Como por ejemplo:

```
 <input data-checkboxinsumo name="checkbox_102" type="checkbox" style="margin: 0">
```

He intentado esto pero no me funciona.

```
 $('[data-checkboxinsumo]':checked)
```

Se supone que debe usar la lógica AND pero no encuentro aún como.

Comment: Me parece que la sintaxis es algo así `<input type="checkbox" name="algo">`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Una posible sintaxis sería esta:

```
$('input[data-checkboxinsumo]:checked')
```

Aquí dejo un snippet para que lo compruebes:

```js
$('.action').on("click", function() {
  console.log($('input[data-checkboxinsumo]:checked').length)

  arr = []
  $('input[data-checkboxinsumo]:checked').each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).attr("name"))
  })
  console.log(arr)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-checkboxinsumo name="checkbox_102" type="checkbox" style="margin: 0">
<input data-checkboxinsumo name="checkbox_103" type="checkbox" style="margin: 0">
<input name="checkbox_104" type="checkbox" style="margin: 0">
<input data-checkboxinsumo name="checkbox_105" type="checkbox" style="margin: 0">
<input name="checkbox_106" type="checkbox" style="margin: 0">
<button type="button" class="action">
¿Cuantos data-checkboxinsumo hay seleccionados?
</button>
```